# Ajax interfering with other page elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've made a little form, which is submit's to itself using ajax, got everything working form-wise. When I put my ajax post code in however, my other javascript functions have stopped working (error: ___ is not defined) and my radio buttons, which should be exclusive (selecting one deselects the other) has stopped working also (since the addition of the ajax code)

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/dmge51g8/

This code is working fine, when the ajax code is taken out, yet gives an error in my browser console with the ajax post.

```
function newOrExisting() {

    if (document.getElementById('typeNew').checked) {

        document.getElementById('newProviderInput').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('existingProviderInput').style.display = 'none';

    } else if (document.getElementById('typeExisting').checked) {

        document.getElementById('existingProviderInput').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('newProviderInput').style.display = 'none';
    }
};

function clearForm() {

    document.getElementById("createPanelForm").reset();

};
```

**UPDATE**: Removed the part about radio buttons (updated JSFiddle)

Comment: You don't require those `;`s at the end of function definition.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry, it's my first attempts at introducing javascript to my php. Are those ; likely to cause error?

Comment: No no. They don't cause any errors. Don't worry.

Comment: Nope, they do not cause any error. To your radio button problem - they need to have the same `name` attribute.

Comment: `<input type="radio" value="1" id="typeExisting" name="typeExisting" onclick="newOrExisting();">` remove `javascript:`

Comment: One thing I noticed is, you are mixing pure JavaScript and jQuery. That's crazy. Then you need to give your radio buttons, the same name, but different values. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I've renamed the radio buttons to have the same name. This has solved the issue that it was possible to select both radio buttons. The remaining issue is that my javascript functions (newOrExisting, and clearForm) are not working now.

Comment: @Jurik Thanks, that has solved part of my issue (now radio buttons are exclusive)

Comment: What error are you getting? When I try to submit, the only error I see is the `The following error occurred: error NOT FOUND` which is due to the http 404 on the ajax request. I don't see any other errors in your fiddle.

Comment: @phreakv6 There are 3 functions in my javascript (ajaxPost, newOrExisting, and clearForm). I'm getting error that the latter two are not defined, and therefore parts of the form are not being hidden or shown.

Comment: You can see the error if you click the radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid defining the newOrExisting function as a variable and assign it directly to the click event on the radio buttons like this:

```
$(".radio input").click(function() {
  if (document.getElementById('typeNew').checked) {
    document.getElementById('newProviderInput').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('existingProviderInput').style.display = 'none';

  } else if (document.getElementById('typeExisting').checked) {

    document.getElementById('existingProviderInput').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('newProviderInput').style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

This would be more in line with the way you have attached the ajax functionality to the form.

Answer (score -1):

In the HTML part of your code, name of your radio buttons are different.

```
name="typeExisting"

name="typeNew"
```

This is allowing two different radio buttons to be treated separately (and you are being able to select both)

Comment: I've removed this section from my question, it was resolved via comments. I had wrongly assumed this was a part of my main issue.